# What is the proper input datatype for the operator []?

Tags: c, arrays, memory

When accessing an array we use the operator `[]` like so:

```
int a[5];
...
a[b] = 12;
```

What is the proper data type for the variable `b` above?

I've found that `a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a + b)`, which makes me think that I would want `b` to be `void*` or `size_t` but, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of `a` and `b` must be a pointer, and the other must be any integer type. A proof follows.

Since `a[b]` is identical to `(*((a)+(b)))` per C 2011 (n1570) 6.5.2.1 2, `a` and `b` may be any types such that the latter expression is defined.

Per 6.5.3.2 2, the operand of the unary `*` operator must have pointer type. Therefore, the result of `(a)+(b)` must have pointer type.

Per 6.5.6, the binary `+` operator accepts various combinations of types, but the only one that yields a pointer type is the combination of a pointer and an integer, as described in 6.5.6 8.

According to 6.5.6 8, an integer may be added to a pointer, and the result has the type of the pointer operand. Clause 6.5.6 makes no distinction about the order of the operands of `+`, so they may be in either order. Thus, either of `a` and `b` may be the pointer, and the other will be the integer.

Comment: I will always prefer `int` inside `[]` because its most popular, also `int[array]` not as clear as base/index. Second `array[++i]`  is understood to me but `++i[array]` not (infect both are not same), Moreover `i[++array]` is error for array_name.

Comment: That's only if you can assume your arrays are not huge, which is almost always true (except when it isn't of course); see http://ewontfix.com/9/ :)

Comment: @loreb Interesting link :)

Answer (score 5):

From the C standard(**ISO/IEC 9899:TC2**) Sec **6.5.2.1 Array subscripting**

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets `[]` is a subscripted
>   designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator `[]`
>   is that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`. Because of the conversion rules that
>   apply to the binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the
>   initial element of an array object) and **E2 is an integer**, `E1[E2]` designates the `E2-th`
>   element of `E1` (counting from zero).

Comment: Hypothetically, would a long work as well? Or would it be cast to an integer?

Answer (score 0):

`b` is known as Index which is a number.So you can deal with it as integer.`a[b]` will access `b`th element of array `a`.

`*(a + b)` will give value at `(a + (b * sizeof(data type of array element)))`

Answer (score 0):

A few types can work, due to implicit conversion.

A `char` will be promoted to `int`. An `int` or `unsigned int` will work too. `short` or `unsigned short` are valid types too.

Even if `a[b]` is the same as `*(a + b)`, `b` cannot be a pointer, because `a` is already a pointer. The binary operator `+` doesn't accept *two* pointers.

Comment: The expression `a[b]` is legal in C when `a` is any integer type and `b` is a pointer, as well as vice-versa. The binary `+` operator does accept either a pointer and an integer or an integer and a pointer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Edited so now its clear that I meant two pointers. Your remark is true, but I never went against it.